# Review of code reviews?

Tags: discussion, status-declined

[image: review of code reviews?]

I'm just wondering if there is any need to change the 'review' label here or (much worse) change the name of this site, since review in the title bar means something very different from review in the content header? I know this is standard for SE sites, I just noticed it and thought it seemed a little odd. Perhaps some new users not familiar with SE might get a little confused. You could at least put a tooltip on the buttons in the title bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Winston mentioned in his answer, it's not something we can change. However, I doubt this is of consequence. If a new user is confused and clicks "review", they'll realize their mistake immediately and no harm will be done.

I see this as a quirk we can live with.

As for showing additional tooltips for clarification, you can file a feature request on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) which is the right place for changes that apply to the whole Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: you also need so much reputation for the review link to show up in your title bar.

Answer (score 1):

We are unable to make site-specific language changes.

Comment: Fair enough (I figured that would be the case), but what about tooltips? AFAIK they're missing across all of SE. May be good to add for general information.